# gcc linker not finding linked libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I'm porting a small program to run on my RPi from my windows machine. The code is correctly ported but I'm having some issues with the linking process. Googling or searching on here has yielded nothing that worked. My .so files are correctly lying in the /mnt/client/dbg/ directory on external storage, can that be an issue?

```
g++ -shared -o dbg/socketwrappers.so socketwrappers.o
g++ -shared -o dbg/mylibrary2.so mylibrary2.o
g++ -shared -o dbg/mylibrary3.so mylibrary3.o

g++ -L/mnt/client/dbg/ -o dbg/client client.cpp -lsocketwrappers -lmylibrary2 -lmylibrary3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsocketwrappers
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylibrary2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylibrary3
```

Filetree from pwd (/mnt/client):
├── ./dbg
│   ├── /socketwrappers.so
│   ├── /mylibrary2.so
│   └── /mylibrary3.so
├── ./makefile
└── ./client.cpp

Comment: Wait... Is there really a dbg folder in the dbg folder? because that's exactly what your somewhat odd diagram picture suggests

Comment: the full path relative the root is given on every step. I see how its confusing. i will edit it

Comment: Name your files `libnamehere.so`, not `namehere.so`. The `-l` specifier prepends `lib` and appends `.so` and/or `.a` when searching for the targets to bring in to the fold.

Comment: It looks like to me as if you do link `-lsocketwrappers` but your object file is called `socketwrappers.o`. First of all, it must be an `.so` file (dynamic link) if you want to link like that. Second, it would expected to bare the prefix `lib`, e.g. `libsocketwrappers.so`, when you do `-lsocketwrappers`. So your output names are wrong in the compilation calls.

Comment: Tried it without luck. I get the same result. I have tried ordering. Adding and removing the extension (.so, I found some conflicting posts saying either way. I'm confident the extension should not be included). Including full and relative path to the linked libraries. With and without library path (-L), et.c.. I find it very odd. 
I'm leaning towards it being an issue with my RPi environment.

Comment: Could you state exactly what you tried (e.g. did you try my suggestion as stated without changing the linker step?) and also which error message you obtained.

Comment: @WhozCraig

You were absolutely correct with having to prepend lib. Worked perfectly. I work mostly on Windows and that's not a necessity there.

For future reference, if I don't want to name my libraries prepended with "lib"[mylib]. Can I add a flag somewhere?

Comment: @ypnos
Comment only allowed one notification. But yours and WhozCraig tip with prepending "lib" worked. I had no idea. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: If you want to forego the lib prefix you can use `-l :<filename>`, e.g. `-l :socketwrappers.so`, but I would always just follow the established best practices if I don't have a convincing reason not to.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'll stick to what's established, knowledge is usually not a bad thing however. If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.